# Should "terrariums" tag be renamed to "terrarium"?

Tags: discussion, tags

[This question](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/751/how-often-should-a-hermit-crab-tank-be-cleaned) was asked today and tagged with the tag [terrariums](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terrariums).  Should that tag be renamed to [terrarium](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terrarium)?

Comment: Related meta question: [Do ALL tags need to be made plural?](http://meta.pets.stackexchange.com/questions/392/do-all-tags-need-to-be-made-plural)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the tag should be renamed [terrarium](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terrarium).  It should be singular, just like [aquarium](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aquarium), [pond](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pond), [cage](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cage), and [enclosure](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/enclosure).

In a related note, someone created the tag [terarrium](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terarrium), which is misspelled.  This misspelled tag needs to be deleted.

Comment: You can fix the misspelled tag by correcting it on the one question where it's used.  (Just delete that tag and add the correct one.)  Unused tags will evaporate.

Comment: Yes, I was the one that misspelled terrarium.  :)  The system won't let me create a "terrarium" tag, because "terrariums" already exists.

Comment: You can't create a tag that's an initial substring of another tag.  I recommend that you change the misspelled one to the existing plural tag for now to at least get all the questions on one tag, and then if that tag gets renamed we won't miss any.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Already done. :)

Comment: If the misspelling becomes common, would a synonym be in order?

Answer (score 1):

I created the [terrariums](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terrariums) if the other misspelt tag has not questions associated with it, it will die.

As for the validity of terrariums, it is not suitable to use [aquariums](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aquariums) for some animals. Giving how popular the site is, I'm pretty sure that the tag will have good use.

Like other tags that will pop up for animal housing etc

Comment: oh wow, people have forgotten to downvote this one!